# Revert array shuffle faster than in O(n^2)

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I want to reverse an array that was shuffled with the function

```
array<integer> shuffle(arr: array<integer>, f: (integer) -> integer) {
    for (i: integer = 0; i < arr.length; i++) swap(arr[i], arr[f(i)]);
    return arr;
}
```

The array passed to this function is `[0, 1, 2, 3, ... n-1]` and **function `f` for any `i` returns a value that is less or equal to `i`**. I have an array returned by the function and I want to restore the results of `f(i)` for each iteration. What I do currently is:

```
array<integer> deshuffle(arr: array<integer>) {
    array<integer> result = [];
    for (i : integer = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i++) {
        index: integer = -1;
        for (j: integer = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] == i) {
                index = j;
                break;
            }
        }
        result.push(index);
        swap(arr[i], arr[index]);
    }
}
```

Here I rely on the fact that the last member of the array can only be shuffled during the last iteration, which means I can find it, push the index and reswap it back and repeat it recursively (this is kinda like the insertion sort if I remember the name correctly). But the trouble is that this code is slow (O($n^{2}$)). Is there any way to do it faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Unshuffling" the array is sorting it, there are $\Theta(n \log n)$ algorithms available (e.g. mergesort or heapsort), and it is not hard to prove that that the problem requires $\Omega(n \log n)$ comparisons.

Or, as the elements are $0, 1, 2, \dotsc, n - 1$, just go through the array, undoing the permutation: see where `i = arr[0]`should go,  where `j = arr[i]`should go, ... until you get back to `0` (you just identified a cycle). Pick the first value not already identified to belong to a cycle, and identify another, and keep going until you've got them all. That clearly is $\Theta(n)$, just that you get the permutation in cycle form.

Comment: If I’m only given the shuffled array and the fact that the function f doesn’t change, I can always create a second array with values o to n-1, shuffle it, and use it to unshuffle the original array.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you are asking. It seems you want to find the values of f(i) for all i.

Problem: You can't distinguish between f(0) = 1, f(1) = 0, and f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1.

Comment: I want to restore values of f(i) used to shuffle the input array from an output array

Comment: f(0) can only be 0 btw because f(i) <= i and it makes it solvable